# How To Check If There Is A Facebook App Present On iPhone With jQuery Mobile

Tags: facebook, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile to create a mobile site and I'm using the standard fb:// link to open the Facebook App when a user clicks on the link to our page.

In an Objective C App I developed in the past, there is code that can check if the application is present on the phone. If it isn't present, it sends you to the http:// version of the site (into Safari).

Is this possible to do with jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You could try performing an AJAX request for "head" to that URL. See what happens.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    url: 'fb://somelink',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The HEAD request type simply returns http headers rather than a complete page. Perhaps this might work.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods